# Regular Expression for finding URL's

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to create a program that will look for any type of URL in a text file, for example hxxp://www.testsite.com/images/logo.png. The following code is my attempt from augmenting online tutorials,(the main one is referenced on top of my code.) but I haven't been able to catch any/all URL's including those embedded in within html tags. I'd appreciate any help or suggestions on what I could try. Thanks.

```
/* Reference: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html 
*/
package de.vogella.regex.weblinks;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader; 
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;  
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class LinkGetter {

//variables 
private Pattern htmltag;
private Pattern link;

public LinkGetter() {
    //Patterns. 
    htmltag = Pattern.compile("<a\\b[^>]*href=\"[^>]*>(.*?)</a>");
    link = Pattern.compile(
"((https?|ftp|gopher|telnet|file):((//)|(\\\\))+[\\w\\d:#@%/;$()~_?\\+-=\\\\\\.&]*)");  

}

public static void main(String[] args){

    String filepath ="TestFile.rtf";

    System.out.println(new LinkGetter().getLinks(filepath));

} 


public List<String> getLinks(String filepath) { 
    List<String> links = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
        FileReader FR = new FileReader("TestFile.rtf");
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(FR);

        String A;
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        while ((A = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            builder.append(A);
        }

        Matcher tagmatch = htmltag.matcher(builder.toString());
        while (tagmatch.find()) {
            Matcher matcher = link.matcher(tagmatch.group());
            matcher.find(); 
            String link = matcher.group().replaceFirst("href=\"", "")
                    .replaceFirst("\">", "")
                    .replaceFirst("\"[\\s]?target=\"[a-zA-Z_0-9]*", "");


            if (valid(link)) {
                links.add(makeAbsolute(filepath, link));

            }

            bufferedReader.close();
        }

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return links;

}

private boolean valid(String A) {
    if (A.matches("javascript:.*|mailto:.*")) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

private String makeAbsolute(String filepath, String link) {
    if (link.matches("http://.*")) {
        return link;
    }
    else if (link.matches("/.*") || link.matches(".*$[^/]")) {
        return "/" + link;

    throw new RuntimeException("Cannot make absolute. File: " + filepath
            + " Link " + link);
}


}
```

Comment: You really need to give us some test cases that don't work. Reviewing code to find input that won't work is off topic for [so]. Related question - [What is the best regular expression to check if a string is a valid URL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url)

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
(https?|ftp|gopher|telnet|file):\/\/([\w\-_]+(?:(?:\.[\w\-_]+)+))([\w\-\.,@?^=%&amp;:/~\+#]*[\w\-\@?^=%&amp;/~\+#])?
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this one on one of my old projects. Should work.

```
 String regex="\\s*(?i)href\\s*=\\s*(\"([^\"]*\")|'[^']*'|([^'\">\\s]+))";
 Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
```